# pyspark: distinctCount - AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'x' given input columns:

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame:

```
Id | field_A | field_B | field_C | field_D
 1 |   cat   |  12     |   black | 11
 1 |   dog   | 128     |   white | 19
 2 |   dog   |  35     |  yellow | 20
 2 |   dog   |  21     |   brown |  4
 3 |  bird   |  10     |    blue |  7
 4 |   cow   |  99     |   brown | 34
```

I would like to only keep the rows, which an Id has `distinctCount(field_A') = 1`. (That is, an Id with only "ONE TYPE" of animal). The final result should be:

```
Id | field_A | field_B | field_C | field_D
 2 |   dog   |  35     |  yellow | 20
 2 |   dog   |  21     |   brown |  4
 3 |  bird   |  10     |    blue |  7
 4 |   cow   |  99     |   brown | 34
```

I started with the approach below:

```
myDF.groupBy(['Id']).agg(countDistinct('field_A')).alias('distinct_A_count').filter('distinct_A_count = 1').show(20,False)
```

Then I got the following error:

```
AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'distinct_A_count' given input columns: [Id, count(field_A)];"
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by **withColumnRenamed** instead of **alias**

```
myDF.groupBy(['Id']).agg(countDistinct('field_A')).withColumnRenamed('count(field_A)','distinct_A_count').filter('distinct_A_count = 1').show(20,False)
```